# Merge 2 tables with same ID into continues ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

so I have a problem here
I'm using sql server 2012

my first table is

```
       TABLE_A
 |ID   | title  | type |

 |1    | how... | ABC  | 
 .  
 . 
 . 
 |40000|fine....| ABC  |
```

my second table is

```
       TABLE_B
 |ID   | title  | type |

 |1    | how... | BBB  | 
 .  
 . 
 . 
 |40000|fine....| BBB  |
```

how to combine both of them to be like this

```
TABLE C
|ID   | title  | type |
|1    | how... | ABC  |
 .
 .
 .
|40000|fine....| ABC  |
|40001| how... | BBB  |
 .
 .
 .
|80000|fine....| BBB  |
```

I'm using this query

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TABLE_C] OFF 
INSERT [dbo].[TABLE_A] (ID, title, type) VALUES (1, 'how...', ABC)
...
INSERT [dbo].[TABLE_A] (ID, title, type) VALUES (40000, 'fine...', ABC)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TABLE_C] OFF
```

then
I'm using this query

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TABLE_C] OFF 
INSERT [dbo].[TABLE_B] (ID, title, type) VALUES (1, 'how...', BBB)
...
INSERT [dbo].[TABLE_B] (ID, title, type) VALUES (40000, 'fine...', BBB)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TABLE_C] OFF
```

but I got the following error

```
violation of primary key PK_ID. Cannot insert duplicate key in object TABLE_C. The duplicate key is (1) ---> until (40000)
```

can someone give me some clue or syntax to insert table B with continue ID when inserted to table_C

Comment: You have an id of 1 in tableA and tableB... so the error is you can't put both in tableC with an id of 1.  You either have to make tableC.id a non-identity, or give them all new id's in tableC.

Comment: so, there's no other way ? maybe just using query?

Comment: You can return both as a query yes, `SELECT * FROM TABLE_A UNION ALL SELECT * FROM TABLE_B`.

Answer (score 2):

How about creating table_c first with an identity column and then inserting into it?

```
create table table_c (
    id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    title varchar(255),
    type varchar(255)
);

insert into table_c(title, type)
    select title, type
    from table_a
    order by id;

insert into table_c(title, type)
    select title, type
    from table_b
    order by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to be able to determine the original table? Will you need to be able to un-merge them? 
If you do, you could try something like...

```
select id * 2, title, type
from table_a
UNION ALL
select id * 2 + 1, title, type
from table_b
```

Combined with identity_insert this will give you an odd numbered id space for table_b and an even number id space for table_a

Does the id space need to be continuous once merged?
If so...

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id, source_table) as id, title, type
from (
select 'a' as source_table, id, title, type from table_a
UNION ALL
select 'b' as source_table, id, title, type from table_a) c
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TABLE_C] ON

INSERT INTO TABLE_C(ID, TITLE, TYPE)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GETDATE()), A.TITLE, A.TYPE
FROM 
      (SELECT TITLE, TYPE FROM TABLE_A
       UNION ALL
       SELECT TITLE, TYPE FROM TABLE_B
      ) AS A

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TABLE_C] OFF
```